# Why calling non-static method inside a static method in C# possible via class instance

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Normally we cannot call a non-static method inside a static method. But if we use a class instance then we can do the above. How does a class instance make it possible for us ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Normally we cannot call a non-static method inside a static method.

That is a gross oversimplification: we cannot call non-static methods in our own class by providing a single method name, because there is no default "this" object. When you write

```
SomeMethod(arg1, arg2);
```

inside an instance method, C# interprets it as

```
this.SomeMethod(arg1, arg2);
```

The same trick does not work inside a static method, because static methods have no access to "this".

> But if we use a class instance then we can do the above.

That's because once you provide another object, there's no need to look for "this" object.

Answer (score 8):

The question is simply: *which instance* are you trying to call the method on? What set of local fields should be assumed?

In the case of an instance method, this is simple: when you call `SomeInstanceMethod()`, an implicit `this.` is added by the compiler, so the answer to those questions is "the current one" (which is, in technical terms, the value of `arg0`). So when you type `SomeInstanceMethod()`, the compiler assumes you mean `this.SomeInstanceMethod()`.

In the case of a static method, there is no implicit `this` that can be  added. You can still call instance methods, but you need to specify the target instance explicitly. `someObj.SomeInstanceMethod()` will work just fine. Note that you can also use `someObj.SomeInstanceMethod()` from an instance method to invoke the method in the context of a different instance.